# excel formula to mysql database using phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

I am using phpexcel to enter data from xlsx to mysql database.
My excel file have values calculated using formula, for e.g:

> =SUM(J21:J24)

My phpexcel script is running fine, however the data using a formula in excel file shows '0'after the upload.

My PhP script is as follows:

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "unhrd_fund_balance");  
 include ("PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");  
 $html="<table border='1'>";  
 $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('sample2.xlsx');  
 foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)   
 {  
      $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();  
      for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)  
      {  
           $html.="<tr>";        

            $ini = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
            $progkey = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
            $grantkey = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
            $tod = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getValue());
            $tdd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getValue());
            $fund = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getValue());
            $orderkey = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getValue());
            $budgetalloc = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getValue());
            $precommit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getValue());
            $commit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getValue());
            $actuals = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getValue());
        $totalcommit = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getValue()); 
            $availablebudget = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row)->getValue());

            $query = "insert into fund_balances(INITIATIVE, FUNDED_PROG_KEY, GRANT_KEY, TOD, TDD, FUND, ORDER_KEY, BUDGET_ALLOC, PRE_COMMIT, COMMIT, ACTUALS, TOTAL_COMMIT,AVAILABLE_BUDGET) values('".$ini."','".$progkey."','".$grantkey."','".$tod."','".$tdd."','".$fund."','".$orderkey."','".$budgetalloc."','".$precommit."','".$commit."','".$actuals."','".$totalcommit."','".$availablebudget."')";

           mysqli_query($connect, $query);

           $html.= '<td>'.$ini.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$progkey.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$grantkey.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$tod.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$tdd.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$fund.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$orderkey.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$budgetalloc.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$precommit.'</td>';
           $html .= '<td>'.$commit.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$actuals.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$totalcommit.'</td>';  
           $html .= '<td>'.$availablebudget.'</td>';  
           $html .= "</tr>";  
      }  
 }  
 $html .= '</table>';  
 echo $html;  
 echo '<br />Data Inserted';  
 ?>
```

In the above code, the '$actuals' uses the excel formula and is null in database.

Comment: You are creating a HTML table with the values. Is `'<td>'.$actuals.'</td>'` also showing 0 for `$actuals`? Or something else? What for example? Also, what kind of field data type is the field `ACTUALS` in your MySQL table?

Comment: The table shows a formula inside it, not zero.

Comment: ACTUALS is a formula in excel sheet to calculate values

Comment: That was not the question. The question was, what kind of field data type is the field `ACTUALS` in your **MySQL table**? I suspect it is numeric. So try `$actuals = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->->getCalculatedValue());`. That will get the calculated value instead of the formula.

Answer (score 0):

The cell's `getValue()` method will return the formula itself; if you want to get the evaluated result of that formula, then use the `getCalculatedValue()` method instead.... as explained in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#retrieving-a-cell-value-by-coordinate)